# What is the smartest approach for this date-conversion?

Tags: r, date, format, data-science

as I was trying to analyze a dataset from kaggle, I run in some conversion issues. I want to retrieve an ISO date à la "2022-04-31" from "4/31/2022 8:26".

My first idea was a classical programming approach via loop and if-logic - way too much afford. The problem here are the missing leading zeroes.

The second approach was to separate the column string values via str_split and then convert it together again:

```
################################################################################
#                             START OF SCRIPT                                   
################################################################################

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))

################################################################################
#                                  ETL                                  
################################################################################

#---->> https://www.kaggle.com/carrie1/ecommerce-data
raw_data  <-  read.csv("data 2.csv", sep = ",")

clean_data <- raw_data %>% drop_na() 
clean_data <-  clean_data[!duplicated(clean_data[,1:8]),]

#
## date conversion
#

split <- str_split(clean_data$InvoiceDate, "/") %>%  plyr::ldply(,data.frame)
colnames(split) <- c("month", "day", "year")
split$year <- substr(split$year, 1,4) 

######
filled_day = as.Date(split$day, format = "%d")
str_day <- substr(filled_day, 9,10)
```

For the day column it seems to work like that, but I am failing to reconvert the month with base and lubridate. Maybe my approach is either too complex or too simple. Please share your ideas with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as.Date` with the `format` `%m/%d/%Y`.

```
as.Date("4/30/2022 8:26", "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "2022-04-30"
```

But this will work only for valid dates.

```
as.Date("4/31/2022 8:26", "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] NA
```

as there is no 31 April.

Another way is using `sub` and `gsub` not testing if the date is valid:

```
gsub("\\b(\\d)\\b", "0\\1"
    , sub("(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+).*", "\\3-\\1-\\2", "4/31/2022 8:26"))
#[1] "2022-04-31"
```

Comment: ok, seems like I simply gave the wrong format information to as.Date. I used "%Y/%m/%d" which gives something like that "0012-09-20" instead of "2011-12-09".